# Работа с одним и тем же файлом из разных программ Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

```
void MainWindow::on_button_login_clicked()
{
    QFile loginsFile("/Users/andrew/Login/logins.txt");
    QFile passwordsFile("/Users/andrew/Login/passwords.txt");
    QVector <QString> loginsVector;
    QVector <QString> passwordsVector;
    QString line;

    if (loginsFile.exists() == false)
    {
        qDebug() << "logins.txt not exists!";
    }
    if (loginsFile.size() == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "logins.txt size = 0!";
    }

    if (passwordsFile.exists() == false)
    {
        qDebug() << "passwords.txt not exists!";
    }
    if (passwordsFile.size() == 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "passwords.txt size = 0!";
    }

    if(loginsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        while (!loginsFile.atEnd())
        {
            line = loginsFile.readLine();
            loginsVector.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Don't open logins.txt";
    }

    if (passwordsFile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        while (!passwordsFile.atEnd())
        {
            line = passwordsFile.readLine();
            passwordsVector.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Don't open passwords.txt";
    }


    if (loginsVector.size() != passwordsVector.size())
    {
        qDebug() << "logins.txt and passwords.txt error!";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < loginsVector.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((ui->lineEdit_login->text() + "\n") == loginsVector[i] && (ui->lineEdit_password->text() + "\n") == passwordsVector[i])
            {
                loginsFile.flush();
                passwordsFile.flush();
                qDebug() << "Files closed!";

                qDebug() << "Logged in!";
                i = loginsVector.size();
                Cabinet cab;
                this->hide();
                cab.exec();
                this->show();
                ui->lineEdit_login->setText("");
                ui->lineEdit_password->setText("");
            }
        }
    }

    loginsFile.close();
    passwordsFile.close();

}

void MainWindow::on_button_registrate_clicked()
{
    QFile loginsFile("/Users/andrew/Login/logins.txt");
    QFile passwordsFile("/Users/andrew/Login/passwords.txt");

    loginsFile.close();
    passwordsFile.close();

    Registration reg;
    this->hide();
    reg.exec();
    this->show();
}
```

В logins.txt хранятся логины на каждой строке, а в passwords.txt пароли таким же образом. Registration - это диалоговое окно, которое я вызываю, и в нём пытаюсь открыть logins.txt и passwords.txt таким же образом, но у меня возникает ошибка:
QFile::open: File (/Users/andrew/Login/logins.txt) already open
QFile::open: File (/Users/andrew/Login/passwords.txt) already open

Comment: скорее всего QIODevice::ReadWrite открывает файл в эклюзивном режиме, если вы только читаете из файла попробуйте использовать флаг QIODevice::ReadOnly. Также не забывайте вызывать file.close() после того, как закончили работу с файлом.

Comment: `close` вызывается автоматически при уничтожении объекта `QFile`. При создании файла на стеке как у автора вопроса, вручную вызывать `close` не обязательно